# Is there a name for a function that takes a type a, and returns a function from a to unit?

Tags: haskell

`something :: a -> (a -> ())`

Is there a name/concept for `something`, the function that takes an a and returns a function from a to unit?

That is given an a, it returns a sink/consumer of a?

Is `something` just `a -> a -> ()`, a bi-consumer of a?

.

What about:
`somethingElse :: a -> (a -> a)`

the function from a to a function from a to a?

`somethingElse` is basically a combiner or binary operator on a, `a -> a -> a`, right?

Comment: `() ≃ a->() ≃ a->a->() ≃ ...` — Do you maybe mean some `m ()` result, rather than just `()`?

Comment: What makes you think this is such a common thing that it deserves a name?

Comment: Looks like some sort of relation.  Functions returning JUST `()` in Haskell are very seldom useful (they come up when you are trying to control strictness, but only then).  But if you replace `()` with some other thing like `Bool` or `m () `for some `m` then I would call this a (perhaps generalized) relation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All possible implementations of `something` are equivalent to

```
sink :: a -> a -> ()
sink x y = ()
```

which you could also write as

```
sink = const $ const ()
```

As you can imagine, this is not a very frequently used function (it is guaranteed to never do anything interesting), and so there is no special name for it.

Your second question, about `a -> a -> a`, is more interesting. If the function is to be polymorphic, i.e. to work over any `a` at all, there are just two possible implementations:

```
first x y = x
second x y = y
```

But this type can be specialized to do something interesting for more specific `a` types.

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

is one example of such a specialization. Indeed this is the type of a binary operator, and any binary operator taking and returning `a` values has this type, or a specialization of it.

Functions of this type are related to Monoid and to Semigroup, in a way, but not all such functions meet the rules necessary to be part of a Monoid or Semigroup instance.

Comment: To be really pedantic, they're not all equivalent to `sink`. `seq` leads to one such exception. (Granted, you'd have to case-match on the `()` for it to matter, but still...)